# What does braket subscript vector mean?

Tags: notation, quantum-mechanics

Reading some quantum theory lecture notes, I came across a notation that really confuses me: $\langle a \rangle_{\vec{u}} $, for $ a \in \{-1, 1\} $ and a unit 3D vector $\vec{u}$.

See equation (15) in [these notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.3081) for context.

Answer (score 0):

It’s a notation for the [expectation value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation_value_(quantum_mechanics)).

Comment: Could you please give some explanation as well? I understand that this is supposed to denote an expectation value, but I don't understand how $a$ can be considered to be an observable, plus how can a vector in those notes represent the state of the quantum system?

Comment: $a$ is not an observable (operator), it's an eigenvalue; and $\vec a$ is just a vector, not a state.

Comment: This is how the Wikipedia article you linked defines the notation:
_Consider an operator $A$. The expectation value is then $\langle A\rangle =\langle \psi |A|\psi \rangle$ in Dirac notation with $\psi \rangle $ a normalised state vector._ Which contradicts what you are saying just above... I'm sure you understand this, but could you help me understand it as well by making your answer more verbose?

Comment: Physicists can be quite flexible in their notation, and using a variable representing an eigenvalue instead of the operator inside the brackets is quite a small change.